# Request Facebook Profile index

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, swift

I am making an app for iPhone that uses some information found in the html code from the Facebook profile page. The app already contains a login with Facebook, but I can't figure out a way to download the html code from facebook into the app.. Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need Facebook API...

https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: I finally fixed it by just using it in a UIWebView and then starting a session, so I could download the html of profile page

Comment: But what you´re doing is insert a browser in your APP.